# Is there a typo in the Stack Overflow Developer Survey report?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2015, typographical-error

[image]

<sup>This image is taken from [the Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2015 report](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015).</sup>

The graph here shows five bars.  The two relevant ones here are the 3rd and 4th, representing the 500-4,999 rep range and the 2-499 rep range.

The relevant text below the graph reads:

> If rep equals money, you would only reach average developer status once you earned between *200-499* rep.

I don't see a 200-499 rep range on that bar graph.

Is the text suggesting that if the graph represented the 200-499 range, it would be 100% (exactly average)?  Or should the text read "2-499"?  Or should the text read "500-4,999"?

Comment: Also, I have 10k+ rep.  Can I have a raise?

Answer (score 5):

As the ranges are increasing equally (one after the other):

```
1. 1            \
2. 2-499         \ 
3. 500-4,999      } They all start one after previous
4. 5,000-9,999   /
5. 10,000+      /
```

It's most likely that this is how they intended the graph to be.

The average wouldn't be between 500-4,999 rep as that would already be above the 100% threshold.

They are assuming that everyone can interpolate the data in the 2-499 (91%) range to understand that 200-499 would yield 100% of the average salary earnings.

To prove this, you can plot the first three percentages (1 rep - 500 rep) in Excel and add a trendline to interpolate the data:

[image]

(Note: It is assumed that the percentages take effect at the beggining of the given ranges because the first and last x value are not "ranged")

Using the formula which was derived from the graph, you can solve for y=1 which would give you 100% of the average salary.

[image]

As you can see, when y=1, x=326.75 which is almost exactly between 200 and 499 reputation, just like the question claims.

Comment: This makes sense.. I like how your username is as such as well. Logic.